# Jackson writeValue() to file not working with relative path

Tags: java, json, file, io, jackson

I'm trying to write an object to json file by jackson.

If i provide an absolute path `"D:/Projects/quiz-red/src/main/resources/com/models/Quizzes.json"` it's working and file appears in the directory

But if i provide a relative path - `"/com/models/Quizzes.json"` i'm just getting `Process finished with exit code 0` in console and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

There is my code:

```
public static void writeEntityToJson(Object jsonDataObject, String path) throws IOException {
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
        writer.writeValue(new File(path), jsonDataObject);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Quiz quiz = new Quiz(5L, "Title", "Short desc");

        writeEntityToJson(quiz, "/com/models/Quizzes2.json");
    }
```

I want to save a file to resources from DataProvider using relative path

[image]

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: com\models\Quizzes5.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createGenerator(JsonFactory.java:1223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:942)
    at com.utils.DataProvider.writeEntityToJson(DataProvider.java:33)
    at com.utils.DataProvider.main(DataProvider.java:50)
```

Comment: Something happens. Add `System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsolutePath())`, and you'll know where the file is actually located. This is not a relative path, BTW. It's an absolute path. Relative paths don't start with a `/`.

Comment: @JB You are right, it creates directory com/models/Quizzes.json on disk "D",
but how make the path relative? I want to create this file (and directories) in resources

Comment: Again, by not starting the path with a `/`. And the path will be relative to the **current** directory, i.e. the directory from which you (or your IDE) executed the `java` command to start your application. Storing files in the source directory doesn't make much sense. You shouldn't pollute your sources with external data. And final users of your app won't have any sources directory.

Comment: @JB i'm getting an exception, pls check the the description, i've updated it

Comment: Don't post an image of your code to ask us why you get an exception. Instead, post your code, as text, and the complete and exact stack trace of the exception, as text.

Comment: @JBNizet updated

Comment: Well, you need to make sure the parent directories of the file exist before writing to a file in a directory. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-. And the directories are supposed to exist, it means that the path is incorrect, or that you're not running your program from the correct directory.